# Passport wouldn't return fields other than username and password

Tags: mongoose, passport-local

In my setup, the route is programmed to print all the data returned by Passport upon a successful authentication:

```
// routes/auth-providers/local.js

import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import passportSetup from '../../passport-setup';

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  (req, res) => {
    const {username, firstName, lastName} = req.body;
    console.log('req.body', req.body);
    res.json({ success: true });
  }
);
```

My local strategy is configured as below:

```
// passport-setup/strategies/local.js

const local = new LocalStrategy (
  (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
      if(err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      // if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      console.log('USER', user);
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
);
```

Of the two `console.log()` statements, only the second one gives out the entire user document, complete with firstName, lastName, etc. However, the first one in my route (`console.log('req.body', req.body);`), only gives username and password. I can even see the user document being serialized:

```
// passport-setup/index.js

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('SERIALIZE', user);
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

P.S.: The repo is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web for reference.

Comment: `req.body` depend on what you sent from client so maybe you just sent username and password.

Comment: I think the `req.body` in this case is being sent by Passport? If you see the code above, Passport is able to retrieve the full user object from the db, as the `console.log()` in `new LocalStrategy ()` shows. Yet, when I try reading the body object in my route, it only shows username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still new with `passport.js` but in the docs [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/), it mentioned that:

> If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the `req.user` property will be set to the authenticated user

So maybe what you need to do is just change `req.body` to `req.user`:

```
const {username, firstName, lastName} = req.user;
```